# Where is the equivalent of Toggle Fullscreen Area (Alt+F10) in Blender v2.8?

Tags: interface

Where is the equivalent of Blender 2.79's Toggle Fullscreen Area (Alt+F10)  in Blender v2.8?

Note: I apologize that my original question contained erroneous information. I do NOT need to know how to Toggle Window Fullscreen as that is located in the Window menu. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can use *Windows > Toggle Window Fullscreen*. I have to check what/if there is a shortcut.

Comment: The entry for `wm.window_fullscreen_toggle` is not in the 2.8 keymap. You can add it though.

Comment: rjg, thanks for trying to help me...I had the wrong shortcut key and name...I am looking for the Toggle Fullscreen Area (Alt+F10) equivalent.

Comment: That one still exists. It's CTRL + Spacebar. You can view and edit all shortcuts in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap*.

Comment: Shift+Spacebar in v2.79 is the equivalent of Ctrl+Spacebar in 2.8. Alt+F10 provides the user with absolutely no interface whatsoever. So much so that people have gotten lost and had to come the this site to inquire how to exit it : )

Comment: Oh right sorry, mixed up the two shortcuts. You can do that by using *View > Area > Toggle Fullscreen Area*

Comment: Which is the same as CTRL + ALT + Spacebar.

Comment: That is it! Thanks rjg.